# Install Windows 7 twice (dual boot) - licensing issues?

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, license

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use my Windows 7 license in a dual-boot configuration?](https://superuser.com/questions/33162/can-i-use-my-windows-7-license-in-a-dual-boot-configuration)
>   [Windows 7 and Vista Activation FAQ: How do language, version, 64-bit or 32-bit, and source affect ability to install and transfer Windows licenses?](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/windows-7-and-vista-activation-faq-how-do-language-version-64-bit-or-32-bit)

I am a software developer and I tend to install a truckload of utilities, servers, IDEs and dev stuff. In time the OS gets overloaded and the boot time goes way up.

A lot of times I need to just start the computer and just visit a site. And I have to wait almost 10 minutes for this. A clean Windows 7 install would boot way faster, on this exact machine.

Therefore I thought how about installing Windows 7 twice, on two boot-able partitions. A mint install and a dev install.

Would this be ok license-wise? How about tech-wise?

Comment: You might consider following the approach used by some netbooks which have a quick boot into a fast lean Linux distribution optimised just for fast booting and Web, Email, MP3 and Photo browsing.

Comment: Umm. Cleaning up/optimizing the current installation to make it boot faster would be much more `tech-wise` solution than to install the OS again. Or you can do what @RedGrittyBrick said.

Comment: You might what to look at an msdn sub.  You can get many licences for dev purposes.

Comment: This is why I never shutdown my computer. Sleep FTW.

Comment: @surfasb: Fire hazard?

Comment: @AndreiRinea: Sleep uses less power than a lightbulb. In that case, a light bulb is more likely to be a fire hazard than Sleep.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

License wise that would not work. 1 license, 1 computer, 1 install. Windows 7 is licensed per install, not per system. In other words, every install of Windows requires it's own license.

Which is why RedGrittyBricks advise is good. Install linux as the dual boot alternative.

From [MS's Windows 7 EULA](http://www.microsoft.com/About/Legal/EN/US/IntellectualProperty/UseTerms/Default.aspx):

```
1. OVERVIEW .
a. Software. The software includes desktop operating system software. This software does not
   include Windows Live services. Windows Live is a service available from Microsoft under a
   separate agreement.
b. License Model. The software is licensed on a per copy per computer basis. A computer is a
   physical hardware system with an internal storage device capable of running the software.A
   hardware partition or blade is considered to be a separate computer.

2. INSTALLATION AND USE RIGHTS.
a. One Copy per Computer. You may install one copy of the software on one computer. That
   computer is the “licensed computer.”
b. Licensed Computer. You may use the software on up to two processors on the licensed
   computer at one time. Unless otherwise provided in these license terms, you may not use the
   software on any other computer.
c. Number of Users. Unless otherwise provided in these license terms, only one user may use the
   software at a time.
```

Comment: It looks like 2a addresses the OP's exact question.

Answer (score 2):

How about using virtualbox and creating a virtual machine for your fast booting clean install. You can install windows without a licence and use it for 4 months - by which time you are probably due another clean install.

I've got multiple licences with my technet account but still mostly use virtual machines for testing