# Different version of Windows 10 on the same machine

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot

I am in need of the Windows 10 version 1803, so I decided to install it side by side with the current version (1903) in  my pc, as I have come across [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1042459/windows10-twice-on-same-machine) which says it's possible. I downloaded a iso file of 1803 and started the setup.

The first two [instructions](https://www.howtogeek.com/214477/how-to-dual-boot-two-or-more-versions-of-windows/) are skippable for me, as my C drive is 500GB and 300 GB of it is free. So I started the setup, but the next instructions doesn't match, as the interface of the setup screen is different, as you can see in the picture. I chose the option not to download update:

[image]

The next screen is forcing me to delete every app, file and setting,( I am to choose the third option, *Nothing* , as the other two options above are disabled) and the reason it gives is as I am installing an older version of windows.

[image]

Is it the right way? I think my C drive will be cleaned if I proceed. What should I do?
**Edit:** I have two other partition , each of them are 200GB (mostly empty).

Thanks.

Comment: The first instructions to install the first windows - you done it already yes. The 2nd instruction - to SHRINK your HDD Partition is required. You cannot install 2 different OS into the same partition. You need to partition your HDD into at least 2 parts, and install the 2nd OS into the 2nd partition. Hence why the instructions to "Shrink" and leave some Empty Space (or even better - make a separate partition) and try to install again. If you don't need the "Dual Boot" you can use something like VirtualBox to have a Windows Virtual Machine. Save you from dual-booting

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply. I have two other partition , each of them are 200GB (mostly empty). But the problem is I can't find any way to specify other partition. And regarding VirtualBox, If I can run 1803 on the new *Windows SandBox*, then I won't go for this hassle. Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is Dual Boot..I think you are installing v1803 on the C: drive which already has v1903 installed on it, if you proceed then yes it will wipe out the v1903 and install v1803.

You have to install v1803 on a different drive eg. D: or E: drive and if you dont have any other drive then you will have to partition your 500GB Hard disk into 2 partitions say 250GB and 250GB. You can do this in Disk management (right click windows icon).

You can search for videos about how to do that, let me know if you need any help.

Comment: I have two other partition , each of them are 200GB (mostly empty). But I can't find any option to choose other partition.

Comment: check if it is a logical partition or a primary partition, for you to install another OS the other drive should be a primary and not logical drive

Comment: download minitool partition wizard free - its very useful software for disk management

Comment: can I do it with the new *Windows SandBox* ? All I want is to test my app to a lower version of windows

Comment: @Muzib also yes you can easily run 1803 in the virtual box but I would say dual booting is the better option...data management will be much easier this way

Comment: Can you show me how, if you don't mind?

Comment: @Muzib show what the virtual box or dual booting ?

Comment: Virtual box, as it'd be perfect for testing my app

Comment: @Muzib open this link: https://www.virtualbox.org/ and download for windows

Comment: keep your windows 10 v1803 ISO file ready

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99330/discussion-between-muzib-and-hamzah-dar).