# Is showing all processes running on a Windows machine to the public a bad idea

Tags: windows

This may seem like a strange question, but this is my current situation.

I was banned a month ago from an online fps game called Valorant for use of an "unauthorized 3rd party program" that affected my gameplay. I've created many support tickets asking what could have been detected by their anti-cheat program, Vanguard. Every response I've received has ended with "we cannot tell you anything because it could affect future anti-cheat investigations." This seems to be a consistent response based on the replies to this reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/VALORANT/comments/lk0t8h/permanent_suspension_for_third_party_software/

As a personal and professional developer, I have tons of programs on my pc and there is no way to know which program(s) might have triggered Vanguard. So I've come up with a plan: once I am unbanned, I will stream on Twitch every time I play Valorant on the same account without changing anything about my system, but will also show every single process's name, pid, and resource consumption on stream and wait until I get banned again. Seems a bit petty, I know, but supports solution seems to be that I must have a dedicated computer for Valorant.

My immediate concern about this plan is that this is probably unsafe, although I don't know enough to know why it is. Any info, concerns, or alternative plans would be appreciated!

Comment: That is completely pointless, but not unsafe. https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The question is kind-of opinion based~ But, I'd still like to comment. Showing *every* single process to the public is a bit risky. The "smart" guys will somewhat know what's going on within your system, which is however, exactly what you want to show to the public. If you decide that you'll show it, you should hide the "windows" processes - Nobody would doubt them to interfere with your game. Also, there is no need to show PID - that would just put your system in risk and it actually plays no role in proving you're not cheating...

Comment: Note that this wouldn't prove anything. If you had cheated, you could've simply removed the program after you got banned. And the devs are not gonna watch your stream.

Comment: @SaaranshGarg That doesn't make sense. Here you go, now hack me:   Process thread: 15804 - Process ID (PID): 2104 - Processname: chrome.exe - Filename: C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe - Handle: 0x0001094A - Title: killallpotatoes.com - Google Chrome...

I can reliably predict which processes are running on Windows 7/8/10/11 computers. Does that mean I can hack all those computers? Do you have evidence for the claim that showing the PID makes me somehow more vulnerable?

Comment: @Gantendo I'm a nice guy, I don't hack peoples computers =] Well it might not be risky as I said (I wasn't thinking clearly...) but showing it is unnecessary, those would still not prove anything...

Comment: @SaaranshGarg Exactly, it wouldn't prove anything, and the devs of the game wouldn't even pay attention to it. OP might be able to report a false positive to the devs of the anti-cheat software but I doubt they'll listen. False positives happen, unfortunately.

Comment: Alternatively if you have some extra money to spare, you can consider [Multi-Booting](https://superuser.com/questions/1042459/windows-10-twice-on-the-same-machine) WIndows 7/8/10/11 (Didn't notice while commenting this, but the OP in the above question seems to be in exact same condition as yours)

Comment: Note that ProcessExplorer and other tools that can display process information often trigger anti-cheat systems.