# Windows 7 Dual boot licensing

Tags: windows-7, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use my Windows 7 license in a dual-boot configuration?](https://superuser.com/questions/33162/can-i-use-my-windows-7-license-in-a-dual-boot-configuration)

I have a single copy of Windows 7 Pro OEM. I would like dual boot Windows 7 on a single PC, one for games and one for applications.

Am I allowed to do this, will Windows pop up a message telling me one of my installs is not valid or something? I really don't want to get to the point where I have to phone up to validate my copy of windows, because that's just rubbish.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Legally its a gray area, but many do it anyway. It will validate ok since it is on the exact same hardware.

Comment: Section 1b of the Windows 7 Home OEM End User license agreement reads: License Model. The software is licensed on a per copy per computer basis. A computer is a physical hardware system with an internal storage device capable of running the software. A hardware partition or blade is considered to be a separate computer.

Comment: Further to the issue of having to Validate Windows 7 over the phone, this "feature" defaults back to normal validation after about a year (ie no need to validate over the phone)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: great idea :)

The configuration you want will work fine. You won't have a problem with the registration as long as both copies are on the same hardware. The registration is done online before you finish the installation, or after OS installation if you don't happen to have internet at the time. This is why you can reinstall an OEM windows on the same machine countless times. Your hardware specs are sent to Microsoft upon online activation.

HOWEVER: I am not sure if Microsoft allows this type of OS usage, you might be violating the EULA, so it might be illegal.

Comment: "You are fine." - " I am not sure if Microsoft allows this type of OS usage, though". These statements seem contradictory to me. "There is no issue" - "You may be violating the EULA"

Comment: What @EBGreen said.  Just because it'll work fine doesn't make it legal.

Comment: Agreed. I have written my response too hastily. I will update it so it makes more sense. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I haven't had any issues with it yet, it seems to work without hitch.