# May I use the same licence for Windows on different partitions?

Tags: windows, windows-8, partitioning, multi-boot, license

I have Windows 8 installed on my tablet and I want to install the same version of Windows 8 on a second different partition of the same disk, on dual boot, possibly from the same ISO.

Given that the computer would be the same, may be possible to use the same license key or should I purchase another in any case?

Comment: You might want to just contact Microsoft and ask them.

Comment: No, it is still 2 installations, which is not covered by a single license. You can do it but is not legal.

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/33184/40928

Comment: From the [Windows 8 EULA](http://download.microsoft.com/documents/useterms/windows_8_english_ca383862-45cf-467e-97d3-386e0e0260a6.pdf): "Under our license, we grant you the right to install and run that *one copy on one computer* (the licensed
computer), for use by one person at a time", which is the same as previous versions.

Comment: According the the License Agreement this is not allowed as it explicitly says **one copy**. Source [MICROSOFT SOFTWARE LICENSE AGREEMENT WINDOWS 8](http://download.microsoft.com/documents/useterms/windows_8_english_ca383862-45cf-467e-97d3-386e0e0260a6.pdf) (pdf)